# Does Dymola have the similar function of "equation browser" like Wolfram system modeler?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, modelica, dymola, systemmodeler

Wolfram system modeler has a function called ["equation browser"](https://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/UserGuide/SimulationCenterEquationBrowser.html#1971148583), the youtube video [here](https://youtu.be/8vEYdNMUj1w)(at 20:58) gives an introduction about "equation browser", I am wondering if Dymola has the same function, it would be helpful to debug nonlinear system.
Also, it is welcome for some other workaround solution, like using python to visualize the equation structures.

Here is the screenshot of the "equation browser".
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the non-linear equation systems and their iteration variables (see the translation log), and you use the Plot Dependencies functionality to trace dependencies for a particular variable. Those are your best options at present.

Comment: I can't see the nonlinear equations, only iteration variables, any idea of how to find the nonlinear equations?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797757/how-to-see-the-nonlinear-equations-of-a-modelica-model-in-dymola

Comment: Yes, you see the variables in the translation log and then you have to follow up on the expressions in Plot Dependencies (in the Simulation Analysis dialog). Simulation Analysis may in any case be a natural starting point, as it highlights which variables are "hard" to solve.

Can you expand on the methodology you would like to use, for example, what would you do when you see such a non-linear equation system after processing?