# How to see the nonlinear equations of a Modelica model in Dymola?

Tags: debugging, modelica, dymola

I build a large model in Dymola, there are nonlinear equations in this model, I wanna know which nonlinear equations decrease the performance and cause an initialization failure, but with the following settings of debugging, I can't see the nonlinear equations in the dslog.txt file, only the iteration variables, how could I find the nonlinear equations?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you see what you need through "Plot dependencies"? In the simulation results view, right-click a variable of interest, then click "Plot dependencies" and it should show the equation used to calculate it.

Comment: Are you using commercial libraries which hide the implementation?

Comment: @MarkusA. Yes, I am using a commercial library.

Comment: @Jack, unfortunately, if the library author has decided to hide the original equations then Dymola will honor that trust and not reveal them in processed form either. And sometimes Dymola errs on the safe side.